# Parent child relationship in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have django model which consist of parent child relationship filed

I want to print parent child relation objects which will seperated by dot(.) like, 
**ParentName.SubparentName.ChildName.subchildName..** etc...

How can i achieve this using recursive technique.

```
 class SomeModel(models.Model)
      parent = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name=childrens).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def print_obj(obj, prefix=''):
    sys.stdout.write('%s%s' % (prefix, obj))
    if obj.child:
        print_obj(obj, '.')
```

But i think that cycle would be better:

```
def print_obj(obj):
    sys.stdout.write(str(obj))
    obj = obj.child
    while obj:
        sys.stdout.write('.%s' % obj)
        obj = obj.child
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check [this documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/intro/tutorial01/) in this example they mention how to call parent child relationship with `poll.choice_set`